# Execute A Dynamic SQL statement Stored in a Column of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table that stores dynamically constructed T SQL queries in one of the table's column. My requirement is that I need to execute the query formed (in my case, some insert statements) and I '**dont want to use a while loop**' to traverse the whole rows and then executing the statements from a variable. Also **I dont want to use a cursor**. The table has around 5 million of dynamically formed SQL insert statements. I had earlier tried this thing using a while loop but it was taking days to complete, and so I dropped it.

Comment: Executing 5 million `INSERT` statements will take some time.  Is a set-based approach not possible?

Comment: You have a horrible data model design and an over engineered solution to a problem.

Comment: Show us some examples of this data.  This is a very bad design, and extremely difficult to address in a way that performs well.  Your best hope is that most of this data can be reduced to something more relational.

Comment: The SQL might not be your only issue.  To do something like this requires a good physical layout as well.  Multiple disks, separate disk controllers if possible, etc..  It's not always the SQL that's the issue.  You need to take some statistics and find out where your bottleneck is.  Good transaction management is also key as pointed out in one of the answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had to look up what `lakh' was :)

As other comments mentioned this is not most optimal approach to DML, please consider refactoring. As it is you can combine your dynamic SQL in batches, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @sSQL nvarchar(max)
SET @sSQL = 'BEGIN TRAN; '

SELECT @sSQL = @sSQL + COLUMN_WITH_INSERT_STATEMENT  + '; '
FROM TABLE
WHERE [limit number of rows]

SET @sSQL = @sSQL + 'COMMIT TRAN '

EXEC(@sSQL)
```

This way you can combine controlled number of INSERT statements into a single transaction. You can control number of inserts by means of WHERE statement (e.g. `WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 and 100` to execute 100 INSERTs at a time) You can loop thru this condition (yes loop, but it it will not be looping thru individual rows, but thru conditions instead e.g.1 - 100, 101 - 200, 201 - 300 etc).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried this method as well. The main problem that occured to me was the inconsistency in the limit of varchar(max) when I was testing it on different machines. Maybe, something to do with the character encoding.

Comment: Nvarchar(max) limit id 2Gb, technically that should be enough. How may statements are you trying to run at one time?

Comment: You can concatenate in your exec to go beyond max.  `exec (@sSQL + @sSQL1 + @sSQL2)`